# How to rename a file (unique name) before uploading and saving the path in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new with PHP and facing great difficulty.
Issue:
1. How to give a unique name to a file to be uploaded.
2. How to save the path in the database.

My code to upload file and save some information in database is:

```
<?php   
    $target = "images/";  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);   
    $name=$_POST['name'];  $email=$_POST['email'];  $phone=$_POST['phone'];  $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);   

    mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
    mysql_select_db ("database") or die(mysql_error()) ;   

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `applicants` VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$pic')") ;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {   
        echo "Your application ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been saved";  
    }

    else {   
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your resume.";
    }
    ?>
```

Please help.

Comment: `md5(microtime().date('d-m-Y H:i:s').$_FILES['file']['name']);` is unique.

Comment: Please take a minute and re-write your question, include code and describe what it means to "give unique name" so we don't try to read your mind.

Comment: @Daan - it's not unique. [This however, is unique.](http://www.php.net/tempnam) Also for the love of anything in IT, do not link w3schools - it's the worst resource online and it simply teaches people WRONG THINGS.

Comment: @N.B. technically true agreed.

Comment: @voidmain It is discouraged to use w3schools. Even though it might be simple and straightforward for beginners, it is inaccurate and even dangerous if you base your future work solely on information from that site.

Answer (score 1):

The technique of generating a random number/string and then hashing that with a cheap algorithm is a good practice, but you need to check if that is indeed a unique value:

**First** generate a random something, and hash it using a cheap algorithm, eg.: `md5`

```
$filename = md5(rand() . substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 30) . rand());
```

Even though this seems totally random at first, MD5 is in fact has a not-so-great collision rate. Therefore, I suggest ensuring that this file does not exist yet. A cycle might be good for this case:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    # Attempt to generate a unique filename
    $filename = md5(rand() . substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 30) . rand());

    # We don't have to keep trying if this file does not exist
    if (!file_exists("files/$filename.txt")) break;
}
```

Now you can proceed with whatever operations you want (eg.: inserting this path into a database).

Comment: Even though your answer will satisfy most users out there, the method used to achieve uniqueness or randomness is not something that people should copy from you. We have a method to generate unique file names - it's called `tempnam` and it will generate a unique temporary name. One can hash it further for whatever means, but using md5 and rand() *should* not be used as definitive answer to generating seemingly random data. However, I doubt that even in highly concurrent environment your method would cause clashes.

Answer (score -1):

1) There's a lot of different ways to give a file a unique name. You could generate a nasty looking guid http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php Or you could use something like this method as Daan mentioned: `md5(microtime().date('d-m-Y H:i:s').$_FILES['file']['name']);`

2) Just store the value of the path into a variable and use a simple sql insert to place it in the database. If you want more details you are going to need to post your code.

Comment: I now have a new problem. I am able to upload the file with a unique name but now i am not able to save any data in the database. I am sure that I am doing some thing wrong. Will you please help me to find the error.